# Chaining GET request with a response Node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to perform a GET request to an API and return the data from the API response to the client. I think the client receives a response before the GET request to the API finishes. How can I change the code to ensure that the response from the API is passed on to the client?

```
if (request.method == 'POST' && request.url == '/locationdata') {
    var body = '';
    request.on('data', function (data) {
        body += data;
    });

    request.on('end', function () {
        var formattedLocation = body.replace(/[\[\]']+/g, '');
        var urlAPI = 'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/166731d8eab28d33a26c5a51023eff4c/' + formattedLocation;

        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        var apiData = '';

        var apirequest = function () {
            https.get(urlAPI, function (response) {
                response.on('data', function (data) {
                    apiData += data;
                });
                response.on('end', function () {
                    console.log(apiData);
                    return apiData;
                });
            });
        }

        response.end(apirequest);
    });

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are ending the response to the client before you get all the data from the api. Moving the `response.end()` call up to the end of the api response should fix it:

```
if (request.method == 'POST' && request.url == '/locationdata') {
    var body = '';
    request.on('data', function (data) {
        body += data;
    });

    request.on('end', function () {
        var formattedLocation = body.replace(/[\[\]']+/g, '');
        var urlAPI = 'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/166731d8eab28d33a26c5a51023eff4c/' + formattedLocation;

        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        var apiData = '';

        https.get(urlAPI, function (apiResponse) {
            apiResponse.on('data', function (data) {
                apiData += data;
            });
            apiResponse.on('end', function () {
                console.log(apiData);
                // send response to browser after we get all the data from the api
                response.end(apiData);
            });
        });

        // remove this because we moved it up
        //response.end(apirequest);
    });

    return;
}
```

Comment: I still get an error. I get the API data in node but I think it is still not being sent to the browser before the response has ended. I get the following error in the browser : `"Syntax error: JSON.parse..."`

Comment: I tweaked the answer and included a full copy of it implemented in your code

Comment: It works! Thank you. Just a minor error in your tweak. I had to change `response.end(apirequest);` to `response.end(apiData);`